# What is the correct way to parse multiple columns out of a single column with data in it?

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a column called 'Message' with this data in it that has multiple columns that are in it that need to be parsed out. I have tried my best to paste it here for copying purposes

```
CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9
Request for API: /api/acmsxdsreader/readpolicyfrompolicyassignment Caller:C2F023C52E2148C9C1D040FBFAC113D463A368B1 CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9 RequestedSchemas: {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}VoicePolicy, {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,  TenantId: 7a205197-8e59-487d-b9fa-3fc1b108f1e5
```

[image: Data in excel format]

I would like to split that message column so that CorrelationID, Callers, Request for API, Requested Schema, and TenantID are all their own column with their associated data in each row.

Here is the final result look

[image]

I would like to know the way to do this in C# if it is possible thank you

Comment: I can't tell from sample posted if data is CSV or fixed column or something else.  There is no CORRECT way.  It depends on the data and there isn't enough of Text sample to determine how to solve this issue.  Posting picture is no help.  And posting one row is no help.  Need to see file exactly as it is in the file.

Comment: @jdweng how can I post the file for viewing purposes?

Comment: You can post text here and share the link.  https://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 0):

If the headers in the message column don't change you can split the message by those fields.

```
string stringToSplit = "CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9
Request for API: /api/acmsxdsreader/readpolicyfrompolicyassignment Caller:C2F023C52E2148C9C1D040FBFAC113D463A368B1 CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9 RequestedSchemas: {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}VoicePolicy, {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,  TenantId: 7a205197-8e59-487d-b9fa-3fc1b108f1e5"  

string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "CorrelationId:", "Request for API:", "Caller:", "RequestedSchemas:", "TenantId:" };  

string[] messageItems = stringToSplit.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None );  

foreach (string item in messageItems)  
 Console.WriteLine(item.Trim());
```